# Extract desired part of a list - PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list (below) and I would like to extract only the necessary components to represent an address in the format of "street and Number, city PIN, country"

`my_list = ['AddressLanguage="eng" ISO="IL" Country="India" City="chennai" Street="XyZ street" HouseNo="3" ZIP="16940"/>\n', 'AddressLanguage="eng" ISO="IL" Country="ISRAEL" City="Madurai" Street="cvbd ROAD " HouseNo="1" ZIP="75140"/>\n']`

Desired Output is `[XyZ street 3, 16940 chennai, India ; cvbd ROAD 1, 75140 Madurai, ISREAL]`

Also 'my_list' is not always in the same format. Sometimes it will not have the 'HouseNo' or the orders might be changed. So I  just wanted to extract only the required components like street and number, city PIN and country that is present in the list and put them in an order mentioned above.

I have tried `[''.join(n for n in i if n in 'Country') for i in my_list]` But this removes the alphabets (Country) from the complete list.

Any help would be really appreciatd.

PS: I am new to python, any advices in learning python would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't your input data an XML data? If yes, [use an dedicated XML parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: Yes, my Input data is XML. I will try XML parser. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def getAddress(rawList):
    toRet = []
    for item in rawList:
        item = item.remove("/>\n")
        rawArr = item.split(" ")
        tempDict = {}
        for x in rawArr:
            y = x.split("=")
            y[1] = y[1:]
            y[1] =y[:- 1]
            tempDict[y[0]] = y[1]
        addr = [tempDict["Street"], tempDict["HouseNo"], tempDict["City"], tempDict["Zip"], tempDict["Country"]]
        toRet.append(' '.join(addr))
    return toRet
```

If your list is as you specify, you need to:

1. Convert each element of list to an array of strings of format "key=value"
2. Make a dictionary from these elements, using "key" as key and "value" as the value.
3. Get the required final address from this dictionary.

Comment: Using Xml tree solved the problem very easily because it creates the dict at the end.